# How to add new row and column in Html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list :

`List A = {'serial1': '8BQZ-CCSU-XY36', 'serial2': 'IEAJ-NVIS-VMKM', 'serial3': '1ZQN-FXHB-FTXT'}]`

I have a script that will read user uploaded excel file and show it in HTML table:
[image]

How can I assign my `list A` item to add a new column based on how many record input by the user?

Expected Output:

For example, if user uploaded a csv file that contain 2 record, it will add 2 new row named "Serial" and append value `8BQZ-CCSU-XY36` and `IEAJ-NVIS-VMKM` to the rows
[image]

My code:

```js
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

  if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
    document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

    excel_file.value = '';

    return false;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

  reader.onload = function(event) {

    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

    var work_book = XLSX.read(data, {
      type: 'array'
    });

    var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

    var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], {
      header: 1
    });

    if (sheet_data.length > 0) {
      var table_output = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';

      for (var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++) {

        table_output += '<tr>';

        for (var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++) {

          if (row == 0) {

            table_output += '<th>' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</th>';

          } else {

            table_output += '<td>' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</td>';

          }

        }

        table_output += '</tr>';

      }

      table_output += '</table>';

      document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
    }

    excel_file.value = '';

  }

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to set an ID for table and use it later to add new rows to that ID.

Answer (score 0):

u should have a 'series' column that is hidden when no. of rows doesn't meet your requirement.